# Saving Fragment's State Through out the application

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application where app has both online & offline mode.
Once the fragment is loaded a network call is made and data is set.
The user makes some changes into fragment UI like adding buttons, Editing TextBoxes etc. I have to maintain that state throughout the application.
I have next & previous buttons, when i press on previous button on the fragment is reloading even though i tried to adding it to back stack while replacing it and calling getActivity().onBackPressed();.

Things I have Tried : 
1) saving the values into bundles is too much data & hard ti retrieve due to bulk of data/values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use viewpager, you can keep the last state of the fragments and it will not reload untill the offscreen limit u set as below.

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit); //limit: integer value >=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have large number of data you want to save, use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html), otherwise you can use Shared Preferences

For more info visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

First get the reference to your shared preferences file

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

after this write to Shared Preferences with

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");

//use editor.apply() if you want to save your data imedialtly
editor.commit();
```

when you want to retrieve the data (onCreateView/onViewCreated)

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

      SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

      EditText editex = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
      editext.setText(sharedPref.getString("key", defaultValue))
  }
```

But keep in mind, Shared Preferences will save and keep your data even if your app is killed/destoyed